# UDP Server, TCP Client?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tcp, network-programming, udp

I'm trying to write a client application in flash, and as far as I know, flash doesn't offer any support for UDP sockets. Is it possible to receive data from a UDP server to a flash (TCP) socket? If it is possible, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope 2 different protocols. You could build a bridge though.

[How to connect to tcp server via node.js/socket.io from client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342752/how-to-connect-to-tcp-server-via-node-js-socket-io-from-client)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe give you a peer to peer service called "stratus"

http://www.flashrealtime.com/tuts/p2p-in-flash.html